# Xcode: set colour of the more navigation controller buttons

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode4, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tabbar application with over five tabs, this means there is a 'More' section. I have a custom background on the more section, but for the life of me can't figure out how to change the colour of the 'Edit' button and the 'Back' button from the other views to black. I assume this will be in the appDelegate file?